# Is it possible to turn on the -d flag to perl within a perl application and have it apply to itself?

Tags: perl

I want to use something like Devel::Trace in a perl program to capture what the program is doing, but I want the application to turn that on itself.  In specific.  I want the program to be able to self-test.  I want to capture logs of what the program does in self-test mode and then use them to verify that the program is functioning properly.  I want to do that from within the program, so that I have access to other information that the program collects, i.e. not just the traces.  And, I don't want to use the -d switch all the time.

I suppose I could have the program recursively invoke itself with the -d switch if it finds it is supposed to self-test and it isn't already in the state where it is on.  I presume there is a way to detect that.  That's a little clumsy, but might be sufficient.

Currently the self-test most does recursively call main, well the same function main calls, but passing in its own argument list to replace ARGV.  But, it can also interact with other modules by overriding variables, e.g. to implement mocking, so I would prefer to stay in the same interpreter, just have the calls to &DB.DB turned on, so that I can capture when functions are called and exited etc.

Answer (score 2):

[`$^P`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EP) is true when `-d` was used.

```perl
BEGIN { exec $^X, "-d:Trace", "--", $0, @ARGV if !$^P }
```

---

You could also use

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -d:Trace
```

Comment: If possible I'd like to do it:

1)  without invoking a new copy of the perl interpreter
2) without having -d on all the time

Comment: 1) `-d` can only be used on startup. 2) You can do the above conditionally.

Comment: Ok, that's what I will do then.  At least I know what I need to check for before spawning a new interpreter with the -d flag on.

Answer (score 2):

###### === update

> I want to use something like Devel::Trace in a perl program to capture what the program is doing, but I want the application to turn that on itself.

After reading the comments, I think you are confused about how the debugger and Devel::Trace interact, and some clarification is needed.

`perl -d` is starting Perl in debug mode and it will  constantly call routines in the debugger's `DB::` namespace, mostly `&DB::DB` for each statement. The "default" debugger is [perl5db.pl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5db), but you can specify another one after the `-d` switch or by setting ENV variables.

And that's how [Devel::Trace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trace) is implemented, look into the source it's only 30 lines longs. It's technically just a debugger.

See also https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts#Writing-Your-Own-Debugger

Now you have two options:

1. You could just write your own `&DB::DB` which checks a flag variable like `$DB::MyTrace` you set interactively to "turn that on" and break the silence, while in constant debug mode.
2. You use `Enbugger->load_debugger` to dynamically load your MyTrace.pm module.

Here is the catch: Activating -d makes Perl considerably slower (~ 10?), so either chose option

1. if you can control the scenarios where you need your trace and slower execution is acceptable.
2. is OK if you can't and a dependency to an XS module like `Enbugger` is OK, i.e. the performance penalty will only hit your production code in case of a bug.

###### === original

I think you want to try out [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Enbugger)

From the docs:

> Enbugger - Enables the debugger at runtime.

> ```
> my $ok = eval { ...; 1 };
>
> if ( not $ok ) {
>     # Oops! there was an error! Enable the debugger now!
>     require Enbugger;
>     Enbugger->stop;
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm not actually looking for a debugger.  I am writing "change detector tests" where I want to see that certain things in some DWIM code happen in a precise order.  So, I'm going to have my own copy of &DB.DB that checks that things haven't "accidentally" changed.  It won't necessarily look at every line, but I do want to see every call/return (as well as the values of key variables) and log them and compare them to saved logs (and when if I like the new logs replace them)   It's a technique that I have found very successful in dealing with subtle semantics.

Comment: As far as asserts ($ok) goes.  I'm satisfied with Carp::assert as a model, although I will look eventually into debuggers.

Comment: It's not a different debugger, so you can change &DB::DB the same way. Or you can load another debugger you patched from perl5db.pl to do what you want.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Yes, reading someone else's source code can often provide one with inspiration.

Comment: I think you should start reading the documentation before reading the source code, like [perdebug](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug) and then some linked in the SEE ALSO section like `perldebtut, perldebguts, perl5db.pl`.

Comment: It might even be possible to activate the `Devel::Trace` you mentioned via Enbugger, please try it out and give feedback. :)

Comment: Yes, of course, I did that.

Comment: I've updated my answer a lot to address some misunderstandings in terminology and highlight options.